# Override keyboard shortcut in Safari 6

Tags: keyboard, safari

In Safari 6, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> opens the first bookmark on the bookmark bar. In Safari 5 I used a macro activated by that same shortcut to activate <kbd>⌘ Commmand</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> to go forward a page.

The reason is that I have another macro activated by the shortcut <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> to go back a page.  It is convenient to use one hand and the two adjacent keys: thumb on the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>key, middle finger on the <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd> keys.

How can this key binding in Safari 6 be changed?

Answer (score 2):

You can add/change any Key Command from
System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

Click the + button then add the info you require. [Later removing any custom binding will revert the app to its default binding]

[image]